# FLASK won't reload after changing code in VS Code

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code

My editor is vs code, I am running flask with the below config

```
{
      "name": "Python: Flask",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "flask",
      "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "application.py",
        "FLASK_ENV": "development",
        "DATABASE_URL": "postgres://localhost/cs50w_project1_development",
        "FLASK_DEBUG": 1,
        "SECRET_KEY": "abcefefe"
      },
      "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--no-reload"
      ],
      "jinja": true
    },
```

It seems all good except flask won't hot reload when I am changing the code. E.G., add an action.

I have to manually reload the flask by clicking the restart button.

Is there any issue with my current config?

Comment: Can you show how you run app(with initialization)?

Comment: just click `Start Debugging` button in vs code

Comment: don't understand. show initialization of app. what server are you using?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is related to init of app. I am just using flask default server. Nothing is changed from default behavior. May be something similar to https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2127#issuecomment-361895333. https://github.com/gamesover/cs50w-project1/blob/master/app.py if you mean this. thank you

Comment: ok, `flask default server`. how you run app? I mean where is `run()`?

Comment: If you are familiar with vs code, in the debug tab, there is a `start debugging` button, click it, the server will be running against the config I posted above

Comment: Are you running the application in debug mode?

Comment: yes, it is.  * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on

Answer (score 26):

Remove the `--no-reload` in the `launch.json`. It's a very old thread but posting the answer here for future visitors.

Comment: Remove the --no-reload in the launch.json, and set "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"

Comment: As a future visitor It helped me.